# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove', how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a function that returns the following error:

```
original_alphabet.remove(value)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I'm not how to fix the error, any help is appreciated. This is my code:

```
def keyword_cipher_alphabet(keyword):
 original_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

 for value in original_alphabet:
  if value in keyword:
   original_alphabet.remove(value)

 keyword_alphabet = ""
 for value in original_alphabet:
  keyword_alphabet += value 

 user_keyword = ""
 for value in keyword:
  user_keyword += value

 result = user_keyword + keyword_alphabet

 return result.upper()
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. Try using a list or something instead.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused because strings don't have a method `remove`.  You might try `replace` instead:

```
$> my_str = 'abc'
$> my_str = my_str.replace('b', '')
$> my_str
'ac'
```